# How can i change the outcome of history-charged events in ASoIaF RPG?

Tags: gm-techniques, campaign-development, song-of-ice-and-fire-rpg

I'm new to this platform and I'm about to launch my first campaign in ASoIaF RPG.

My players asked me if we can set our campaign right at the start of the Greyjoy Rebellion back in 289 AC and since i want to change the outcome of this rebellion a bit, i was wondering if anyone has experience with changing the original story of ASoIaF and maybe has advice for me?

Comment: Welcome to RPG.SE Dolorion!  Take a minute to review the [tour](http://rpg.stackexchange.com/tour) (under help above).  In particular, this site doesn't handle open ended discussion questions well- for that we usually refer querents to a forum, like RPG.net.  It is likely that this question will be closed, but don't let that discourage you- the tour is very helpful for explaining what types of questions are appropriate for the site.

Comment: @Dolorion Generally "do you have advice?" on such a broad circumstance ("I'm playing this game, and I want to jump into the history") is too broad a question, since it'll gather advice of all sorts. Which is great, but our system isn't built to handle that kind of stuff. (Forums would serve you better there.) However, if you have a specific problem to ask about, that'd help: in this case I suspect there's some kind of problem you're foreseeing or experiencing in doing what you want to do (I'm not familiar with your game) and some kind of request, like how to pull it off properly?

Comment: I am going against the flow here and think that the question could be answered adequately. My answer is very generic but I could see a better answer by a scholar of ASoIaF.

Comment: I try to focus on a specific problem next time, nevertheless thanks for pointing out my mistake^^

Comment: I have answered this question...A couple of times: Here's one about [letting players have *canonical characters* as PCs](http://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/9202/what-are-the-consequences-of-letting-players-be-characters-from-a-work-of-fictio/9203#9203) and here's another where I reference [changing the history of Westeros explicitly](http://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/7625/a-campaign-based-on-a-novel-let-the-plot-deviate-or-make-the-pcs-thread-unrela/7658#7658). I think both the question as it stands and those answers are focused enough for this site.

Comment: @Sardathrion This is a textbook example of why holding off with an answer is better, even if it would fit the original form of a question. Now we have a closed question that *could* have been fixed and reopened, but won't be because asking a bad question still got the asker what they wanted. What could have been a good question with a number of quality answers is now destined to be deleted some day.

Comment: @SevenSidedDie: I answered the question when it was opened... It got closed afterwards.

Comment: @Sardathrion Yes, I know. That's why holding off on super-broad questions is better, even when they're still open. They will not survive the votes to close. You saw it heading toward closure, "going against the flow." Now the question is dead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sure, change everything you like as long as (i) the players are aware that your game does not follow the cannon after X date, and (ii) that your changes are internally consistent.

The former is easy but can get players' back up when an NPC acts in a different way that they imagined said NPC would act. But this is just expectation and can easily be managed.

The latter is harder to achieve but not impossible. Sudden changes in NPCs' motivation or thoughts should be taken with care so as to maintain realism within the game world. A lot of Song Of Ice And Fire is based on some character being unaware of something happening or lacking knowledge pertaining to a certain situation.  If those change, then the characters could react differently as to how they do.